# Display custom text on Kendo Loading Indicator

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to use a custom text on `Kendo Loading Indicator`? There is not such a kind of information on [Kendo UI documentation pages](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/window/how-to/display-loading-overlay) but might it be possible to implement a custom property or `css` in order to display a message i.e. *"Please wait!.."* on `Kendo Loading Indicator`? I use the following lines in order to display and hide the loading animation?

```
/* Show Kendo Loading Indicator */
kendo.ui.progress($("#kendo-loading"), true);

/* Hide Kendo Loading Indicator */
kendo.ui.progress($("#kendo-loading"), false);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: The Kendo loading indicator is just a gif where you can't add your own text unless you create yourself a new custom loading indicator or insert dynamically a text after the indicator showing but it's pretty ugly.

Comment: Thanks for informing. I hope this need is taken into account by Telerik Team for the next release...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an example called `customize loading animation text` on the API documentation page [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/ui/methods/progress).

```
<style>
/* By default the text is hidden, re-position the text */
span.k-loading-text
{
    text-indent: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: #0F0;
}

div.k-loading-image
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script>

$(function(){
    //customize the default "Loading..." text
    kendo.ui.progress.messages = {
        loading: "Processing..."
    };
});

</script>
```